# hibernate/spring over jboss

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss

My application is made of Spring+Hibernate, and running well under Tomcat.
I deployed my app (WAR) under Jboss AS 7.1.3, but Jboss seems to take over Hibernate persistence.
I tried to change some settings to disable Jboss JPA, but no more success:

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
 <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
    <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
    <prop key="jboss.as.jpa.managed">false</prop>
    <prop key="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule">hibernate3-bundled</prop>
 </props>
```

When i try my REST call, i got the following Exception.
Anyone could help? i googled half a day with no full solution.

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
        org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
        org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

<b>root cause</b> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:94)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:876)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The `NoSuchMethodError` suggests that you might be mixing JARs from different, incompatible versions of Hibernate. Make sure all your Hibernate JARs are from the same version. Maybe some JBoss common lib directory contains Hibernate files that clash with what your app needs.

Comment: If you're planning to deploy to JBoss only, you could try to remove any JPA related libs from the war file. So that JBoss handles the persistence. If you're using any build tool (maven | ivy | gradle) you can easily set the scope of these libs to provided

Comment: i don't want to use Jboss libs. I want to rely on my WAR embedded libs. I tried many solutions provided in Spring/Hibernate/JBoss web sites, but no one is working :(

Comment: the jboss "hibernate" libs are disabled. But my internal "hibernate-core-5.1.0" lib does actually not have the method "debug" in the class... how can i figure out which lib/conf in jboss call such a method (my app is running well in Tomcat 8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we changed the hibernate version use in our project to match the JBoss hibernate embedded version.

Answer (score 0):

For JBoss you can try to put a file `jboss-app.xml` in the `META-INF` folder of the `EAR`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-app
    PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD J2EE Application 4.2//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_4_2.dtd">
<jboss-app>
  <loader-repository>
    com.company:loader=xxx-ear-loader
    <loader-repository-config>
      java2ParentDelegation=false
    </loader-repository-config>
  </loader-repository>
</jboss-app>
```

If you use `WAR` only you can try to tweak `jboss-web.xml`

```
    <jboss-web>
       <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
          <loader-repository>
            com.company:loader=xxx-ear-loader
             <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
          </loader-repository>
       </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

You need to specify `com.company:loader=xxx-ear-loader`.

> Note for AS 4.2.x and versions till 5.x: As of at least JBoss 4.2.1,
>   the  tag appears to no longer be supported as isolation
>   is ignored. Instead, the following configuration appears to accomplish
>   the same goal:

```
<jboss-web>
   <loader-repository> 
      com.example:archive=unique-archive-name 
   </loader-repository> 
</jboss-web>
```

Refer this
[ClassLoadingConfiguration](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration)

You need to have Hibernate libraries in the`WAR` or `EAR`, of course.

You can delete or replace Hibernate libraries in the JBoss lib folders too.

Comment: thanks for quick answer. I did not package my app in EAR, but WAR.

Comment: @ptitjuju69 Why? :) I just copy it from a provided link.

Comment: @ptitjuju69 I add an another example from a link. Try to various approaches.